# Why does ResourceManager.GetResourceSet return null on the first request after a build? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, resourcemanager

I'm working on a large-ish web application built in C# (asp.net). I've got a simple aspx page that serves localized strings to the client browser for use in javascript controls.  To get the strings, I do the following:

```
ResourceManager _resources = new ResourceManager(_pathname, typeof(ARM).Assembly);
ResourceSet rs = _resources.GetResourceSet(culture, false, false);

//loop through rs and write the keys & values out to the client in plaintext
```

This all works fine, except for the first request to the page immediately after a Clean/Build or a Rebuild (if I simply make some changes, then Build, it works fine). So on the first request I get a null reference exception when I try to iterate the ResourceSet.  If I refresh the page after the error, however, it works fine from then on.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 53):

Second param "createIfNotExist" of the method GetResourceSet has to be true, that tells ResourceManager to load the ResourceSet if not yet loaded.

```
ResourceSet rs = _resources.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
```

Comment: Nice answer, the createIfNotExists put me on the wrong foot. (Perhaps Microsoft should think of renaming the parameter name, loadIfNotPresent)

Comment: We have a #TenYearsChallenge here.

In **2009** the second parameter was **createIfNotExist**,
In **2019** the second parameter is **createIfNotExist** !!!

wasted two complete days on this naming convention ...

Comment: Argh the pain! Thanks for this - Mircosofts really need to change this paramater name!

Comment: Amazing how this name is still an issue in .NET 7, thanks for this answer. The default naming is atrocious! 