# With ResourceManager, why does it work when I call GetStream(...) before GetResourceSet(...)

Tags: c#

I have a strange issue with the C# ResourceManager. The following kind of fails:

```
var rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(myStrings));
var resources = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, false, false);
```

Now 'resources' is null. But the following works:

```
rm.GetStream(""); 
var resources = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, false, false);
```

Why does it only work when I call .GetStream("") first?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case, but might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646233/why-does-resourcemanager-getresourceset-return-null-on-the-first-request-after-a?rq=1

Comment: That's equivalent to GetResourceSet(culture, true, true)