# "GetResourceSet" method of "ResourceManager" [System.Resources] class returns empty - even if it exists in collection

Tags: c#, localization, globalization

I am using following code to retrieve the Resource file values in C#

```
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CN"); // just hard coded to make question simpler
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("SchedulingSystem", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var entry = rm.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, true)
         .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
         .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value.ToString() == input);//input => "No_Records"

        var key = entry.Key.ToString();
        return key;
```

Both Key and Value returns as null, but if I use "Quick View" in Visual studio, I can see the values as shown in the Image, The input "No_Records" can be seen in Quick view of object.

I have also referred stack overflow quesitons like [[Why does ResourceManager.GetResourceSet return null on the first request after a build? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646233/why-does-resourcemanager-getresourceset-return-null-on-the-first-request-after-a?rq=1][1])
[image]

What I might have missed in my c# code?

Comment: There's a simple typo in your code, you want to compare e.Key to *input*, not e.Value

Comment: Thanks resolved. Thanks a lot Hans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the ResourceSet dictionary keys are case or culture sensitive, but there are two possible issues with your implementation:

1. You are using Value not Key
2. You are performing a straight comparison on the values instead of mitigating culture and case-sensitive differences.

Changing to the following should resolve your issues:

```
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.ToString().Equals(input, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```