# c# - ResourceManager and ResourceSet give me empty or null result

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on resources files to translate some texte.

I have the main "RevitString.resx" and "RevitString.fr-FR.resx".
They both have the same keys with translated values and are in public.

I want to use them inside my c# code with the following code :

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = Resources.Languages.Tables.RevitString.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
type = (from ResourceDictionary x 
        in resourceSet 
        where x.Keys.ToString() == _type.Definition.ParameterGroup.ToString()
        select x.Values.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I run this, I got a null ResourceSet and when i look on the ResourceManager, "ResourceSets" is empty with count = 0.

What did I do wrong ?

I already wath some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646233/why-does-resourcemanager-getresourceset-return-null-on-the-first-request-after-a)

Thank you!

Comment: have you tested `where x.Keys.ToString() == "yourKey"` to see if it returns something?

Comment: nvm, your `resourceset` count is 0

Comment: @GibralterTop Yes I tried and got a null execption too because of my count = 0 :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39858236/5224021 maybe something here can help

Comment: @GibralterTop It works ! Thank you :)

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to post your working code/solution when you can for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to GibralterTop who gave me the good link.

Here is what I use know

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = Resources.Languages.Tables.RevitString.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
switch(enumerator.Key)...
```